# use two different Internet connections simultaneously via Mobile USB Connections?

Tags: internet

I have two Nokia mobiles with two different network operators. I am using the USB cable to connect to the two different internet connections. But only one internet connection is used and another stays idle.

I have tried the forcebindip but it is not working. I think its because i am using the USB cable connection and NOT the NIC LAN connection.

How can i use the forcebindip in above case ?

Is there any way to convert this usb connection to virtual NIC LAN connection ?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick - I thought that too at first, but I think he's specifically trying to use them per-app with ForceBindIP, not tie multiple connections together.

Answer (score 0):

From the ForceBindIP page [here](http://www.r1ch.net/stuff/forcebindip/) (last updated in 2009):

> As of version 1.2, all known functions in WS2_32.DLL that either explicitly or implicitly bind to an interface are intercepted. **Please note however that certain programs may still end up using the default interface if they implement connections that do not use the standard winsock functions.**

So unless you can be sure your program is using "standard" Winsock calls, then you can't be sure if it will work with ForceBindP.

You may want to try it with a few different programs and see if you get better/different results.

Also, keep in mind that ForceBindIP was never tested beyond Windows 2003 (at least not according to the page) so it's compatibility with newer Windows versions probably isn't guaranteed. :)

Comment: Thanks. I have tested it with all the compatible programs listed on their site but no luck. Only 1 conn is utilized. I think the problem is with the usb connection since forcebindip works with NIC's only ?