# Two applications use two Different connections to download simultaneously?

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, internet, ethernet

Since I have a download cap in one connection [LAN] but faster speed compared to my [3g] connection which has no cap, I want to use [LAN] for browsing and [3g] for downloads/torrents. But as I've found out that only one connection will handle all the traffic even if both are connected.

Some previous questions suggest load balancing but that's not what I want for the reason above.

[ForceBindIP](https://superuser.com/questions/338298/use-two-different-internet-connections-simultaneously-via-mobile-usb-connections) is outdated and not working anymore.

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Better addressed to SF - Layer 4 switches aren't HomeUser territory

Comment: @LazyBadger Before you send people to SF, you should make sure you know what you're talking about. In this case, you are completely incorrect. This is entirely **off-topic** for SF, per the first line in our faq.

Comment: @MDMarra - ok, we have collision of interests. Nobody (almost) have knowledge to answer here, and SF is prohibited area. **Rules for humans or humans for rules?**

Comment: @LazyBadger if you have a problem with SF's rules, the proper place to ask about it is meta.serverfault.com. Not in the comments to someone else's question. If a question is on-topic on one site that doesn't have the experts, but is off-topic on another site, it should stay on the site that it's on-topic for. No question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own ques:

So far Ive found that the easiest (and the only) way to do it is use two separate windows accounts with different default connections (one dialup and another LAN). Running any applications from withing one particular account will use its default network only.

**EDIT::** doesn't work in the long run. Works for sometime, then it just defaults to same connection.